# Calling parent class function to compare parent and child classes

Tags: python, c++, class, methods

I was doing a Python course and the idea of using parents overridden function to compare parent and child classes popped up. Basically:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.a < other.a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.b < other.b

a = A(2)
b = B(1,3)
print(a < b)
#print(b < a) # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribuite 'b'
print(A.__lt__(b,a)) # so we call this instead
```

Now, I would like to do the same thing in C++

```
class A{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    bool operator<(A t){ return a < t.a; }
};

class B: public A{
    int b;
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {}
    bool operator<(B t){ return b < t.b; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(2);
    B b(3,1);

    std::cout << (a < b) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << (b < a); // error, A has no b attribute
    //std::cout << A::operator<(dynamic_cast<A&>(b),a); // basically what I would like to happen
    std::cout << a.operator<(dynamic_cast<A&>(b)) << std::endl; // here I would like to reverse a and b

    return 0;
}
```

There has to be a way to do it, I don't know if it's just lack of knowledge of methods in C++.

I know I could just overload operator>= instead, but that's not a point, comparison is just an example here.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you compare two `A&` objects that really are `B` objects? I.e. `B x; A& y = x; return y < y;`? Should it compare the `a` or `b` member of each?

Comment: If I cast `x` on `A&` then it should compare them by the `operator<` defined in `A` class, so compare them by `a` attribute. 
Actually your question helped me get it, I should simply cast the `B` object on `A&` and then call the operator for it, that is:
 `dynamic_cast<A&>(x) < y`

Comment: Doing binary operations like this is meaningless and dangerous for the most part. You can implement what you want to toy around and explore how C++ works, but if you do it in real code, you will regret it. Just don't. Please give us a real world example of what you are trying to do. Perhaps a better design choice is in order.

Comment: It is a purely theoretical question, as the same thing can be achieved so easily in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: things like these are better never done in real code, with comparison at least. This is just an example use of some C++ constructs.

Variant 1: static dispatch.

```
class A{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    friend bool operator<(A& x, A& y){ return x.a < y.a; }
};

class B: public A{
    int b;
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {}
    friend bool operator<(B& x, B& y){ return x.b < y.b; }
};
```

This code compares A and B objects according to their *static* type. So if you have:

```
B b(0, 42);
A& a = b;
```

`a` will behave like `A` in comparisons. The system is based on operator overloading.

---

Variant 2 : dynamic dispatch.

```
class A;
class B;

class A{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
    bool operator<(A& t){ return t.compare(*this); }
protected:
    virtual bool compare (A& t);
    virtual bool compare (B& t);
};

class B: public A{
    int b;
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {}
protected:
    bool compare (A& t) override;
    bool compare (B& t) override;
};

bool A::compare(A& t) { return t.a < a; }
bool A::compare(B& t) { return t.a < a; }
bool B::compare(A& t) { return A::compare(t); }
bool B::compare(B& t) { return t.b < b; }
```

This code compares A and B objects according to their *dynamic* type. So if you have:

```
B b(0, 42);
A& a = b;
```

`a` will behave like `B` in comparisons. The system is based on double dynamic dispatch, also sometimes known as visitor pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question and gives me some things to study.